# Using iron-media-query and dom-if Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using iron-media-query to display toolbar menu items using Polymer 1.0 but it's not rendering on the mobile device as expected.

The menu are well rendered if i resize the desktop web browser (Google Chrome) but if I load the page on my phone Note 3 it doesn't respect the rule. Might be there is something I'm doing wrong.

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 750px)" query-matches="{{ isBigWidth }}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{ isMediumWidth }}"></iron-media-query>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{ isBigWidth }}">
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <iron-icon icon="settings"></iron-icon>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <iron-icon icon="settings"></iron-icon>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <iron-icon icon="settings"></iron-icon>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{ !isBigWidth  }}">
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{ isMediumWidth  }}">
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
        <a href="/">
            <paper-button>
                <span class="vertical-align">Settings</span>
            </paper-button>
        </a>
    </template>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{ !isMediumWidth }}">
    <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"  id="icon_button2"></paper-icon-button>
</template>
```

Comment: I think `max-width` would be a much better option that `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries using pixels are based on phone viewports, so the note 3 should be treated as a 360px x 640px device http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=note%203

Also, make sure to include in the header:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```